# Enabling radio button on textfield value

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the value is "Runner" the radio button enabled, then the radio button is enabled, otherwise the radio button gets disabled. The following code follows always disables the button, I'm not sure why.

```
var role = $("#txtRole").val(empdata.EMPROLE.toString().toUpperCase());

if(role != 'Runner' || role != 'RUNNER') {
    $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
} else if(role == 'Runner' || role == 'RUNNER') {
    $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled',false);
}
```

Comment: `$("input[type=radio]").prop('disabled', !(role=='Runner' || role=='RUNNER'));`

Comment: then what comes under if condition

Comment: just that line will take care of both

Comment: @guradio — If OP is applying `toUpperCase`, why to compare with `lower-case` string ?

Comment: @Rayon sorry didnt check that. i just check the condition i think he can fix that :)

Answer (score 0):

(Ignoring your condition,) you should use `removeAttr('disabled')` instead of `attr('disabled', false)`.

Also, your condition should simply be:

```
if (role !== 'RUNNER') {
    $(...). attr('disabled', true);
}
else {
    $(...). removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little bit confusing here as it sets the value. I don't know if it also gets after setting.

`var role = $("#txtRole").val(empdata.EMPROLE.toString().toUpperCase());`

You need to get the value after setting it:

```
// setter
$("#txtRole").val(empdata.EMPROLE.toString().toUpperCase());
// getter
var role = $("#txtRole").val().toUpperCase();
```

Then you can set or remove the disabled attribute

```
if( role != 'RUNNER' )
    $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
else
    $("input[type=radio]").removeAttr('disabled');
```

I suggest using a `change` event to check the value if the field is open to user edits.

```
$("#txtRole").on("change", function(){
    var role = $("#txtRole").val().toUpperCase();
    if( role != 'RUNNER' )
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else 
        $("input[type=radio]").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

and when the change occurs:

```
$("#txtRole").val(empdata.EMPROLE.toString().toUpperCase());
$("#txtRole").trigger('change'); //just to be sure
```

it'll automatically be checked and modified.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm used to use `attr` for a long time. My bad.

Comment: Solution is as simple as __`$("input[type=radio]").prop('disabled', role != 'RUNNER');`__

Comment: I'm not counting on `$("input[type=radio]").prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: Did not get you :( Also note that `jQuery.val` returns the `String` which is value of the `input` hence `getter` and `setter` is not really needed..

Comment: Why don't you write your own answers in a single answer? Just commenting everywhere won't help you.

Comment: Ooh.. Extremely sorry.. You have posted an answer which is not 100% correct and it is my duty to correct those so that it should not mislead future users who may refer this answer.. Good luck..!

Comment: I'm saying that you should write your 100% correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#txtRole").val('Runner');

    $("#txtRole").change(function()
     {
      var role = $("#txtRole").val().toUpperCase();
      if(role != 'RUNNER') 
        {
        $("input[type=radio]").prop('disabled', true);
        } 
     else if(role == 'Runner' || role == 'RUNNER') 
        {
        $("input[type=radio]").prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

<input type='text' id='txtRole' />
<input type='radio'/>
        </body>


    </body>
    </html>
```